# Is it possible to specify an outbound proxy using the twilio-go client library?

Tags: go, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to use twilio-go to send calls and sms messages but the host running the client has to go through an outbound proxy to reach the internet. Is there a way to specify a proxy for the twilio client to use?

Comment: Added an example below, see if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can construct your twilio-go [Client](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/twilio/twilio-go@v0.17.0/client#Client), which consumes [*http.Client](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client), which you can set to use the proxy.

## UPD:

Made a little example to show how that would work:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"

    "github.com/twilio/twilio-go/client"
    apiv2010 "github.com/twilio/twilio-go/rest/api/v2010"
)

func main() {
    from := os.Getenv("TWILIO_FROM_PHONE_NUMBER")
    to := os.Getenv("TWILIO_TO_PHONE_NUMBER")
    body := os.Getenv("TWILIO_MSG_BODY")

    accountSid := os.Getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID")
    authToken := os.Getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN")

    proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("http://localhost:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    c := client.Client{
        Credentials: &client.Credentials{
            Username: accountSid,
            Password: authToken,
        },
        HTTPClient: &http.Client{
            Transport: &http.Transport{
                Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl),
            },
        },
    }
    c.SetAccountSid(accountSid)

    params := &apiv2010.CreateMessageParams{
        To:   &to,
        From: &from,
        Body: &body,
    }

    textMsgSvc := apiv2010.NewApiServiceWithClient(&c)
    resp, err := textMsgSvc.CreateMessage(params)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    } else {
        response, _ := json.Marshal(*resp)
        fmt.Println("Response: " + string(response))
    }
}
```